# Recursive Backtracking in simple graph

Tags: java, recursion, graph, backtracking, adjacency-matrix

imagine the following simple graph:

[image: graph]

Every entity has an index starting count 0 (so A has index 0, B has index 1 and so on).

A and B are connected, so the distance between them is 1, so f.e. the distance between A and D is 2, because they are both connected with F.

How to implement a method in java, that takes two indices and a distance as parameters, and performs a recursive backtracking in order to find out whether the two given entities are reachable within the given distance ???

So, if I call the method with parameters (3, 0, 2), then it should return true, because 3 is D and 0 is A and the distance between them is 2, so it's true.

What I've tried:

```
public boolean backtracking(int index0, int index1, int d) {

    boolean reachable = relation[index0][index1];

    if (d > 0 && !reachable) {
        for (int i = index0+1; i <= index1+d; i++) {
            backtracking(index0+1, index1, d-1);
        }
    }

    return reachable;
}
```

I have an adjacency-matrix with the relations inside the 2D-boolean-array relation, based on the graph.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you written so far, and how is it deficient?

Comment: Where is your code that you have tried?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score -1):

The following code does what you want.

The `canReach` methods is a recursive method. If the allowed `distance` is smaller than zero, then we return false. If the node given to `canReach` is equal to this, then it is reachable. Otherwise, iterate over the neighbours of the `Node` with the distance decreased by 1.

**Code:**

```
public class Node {
    private Set<Node> neighbours = new HashSet<Node>();

    public Node() {
    }

    public void connect(Node node) {
        if (neighbours.add(node))
            node.connect(this);
    }

    public boolean canReach(Node node, int distance) {
        if (distance < 0)
            return false;
        if (this.equals(node)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            for (Node neighbour : neighbours)
                if (neighbour.canReach(node, distance - 1))
                    return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}

private Graph() {
    Node a = new Node();
    Node b = new Node();
    Node c = new Node();
    Node d = new Node();
    Node e = new Node();
    Node f = new Node();
    a.connect(b);
    b.connect(c);
    b.connect(e);
    a.connect(f);
    f.connect(d);
    System.out.println(a.canReach(d, 2));

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Graph();
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
true
```